# indexOf() not working as expected

Tags: apex, trigger

I have the following snippet:

```
for(Account eachAccount : accountWebsites){
            // if there's a match, assign the contact to the account and update
            System.debug('Searching for ' + myConDomain + ' in ' + eachAccount.Website +
                         '; index is ' + myConDomain.indexOf(eachAccount.Website));
            if(myConDomain.indexOf(eachAccount.Website)!=-1){
                eachAccount.OwnerId = myCon.id;
                update eachAccount;
            }    
  }
```

I have a test class where there definitely should be a match for the indexOf() but oddly, I get no match as shown by the output of my System.debug:

15:10:00:955 USER_DEBUG [19]|DEBUG|Searching for bark.com in www.bark.com; index is -1

Is there something I'm doing wrong or some concept about indexOf() that I'm not understanding?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're searching your substring (bark.com) for the full website name ([www.bark.com](http://www.bark.com)) rather than the other way around. The string passed into the indexOf function should be what you are searching for, not what you are searching against.

This code should work:

```
for(Account eachAccount : accountWebsites){
    if(eachAccount.Website.indexOf(myConDomain)!=-1){
        eachAccount.OwnerId = myCon.id;
        update eachAccount;
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it!